# NServiceBus .netcore + MySql

Tags: mysql, .net-core, mariadb, nservicebus

I’m trying to configure NServiceBus in a simple .netcore3.1 console application to use MySql.

I have the Persistence set to **SqlPersistence** with a **SqlDialect.MySql** and i'm using the *SqlServerTransport**.

My connection string is of type **MySqlConnection** :

```
server=localhost;user=root;database=database;port=3306;password=password;AllowUserVariables=True;AutoEnlist=false
```

When I run the application, I get the error :

```
System.Exception: ‘Pre start-up check failed: Could not open connection to the SQL instance. Check the original error message for details. Original error message: Keyword not supported: **port**
```

Does anyone have any ideas what it might be? Any help would be great!

FYI. I have efcore up and running using and connecting to the MySql database.

Comment: Did you take a look at the official docs? https://docs.particular.net/persistence/sql/dialect-mysql?

Comment: Yes. I've just described in the post everything that the doc explains

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I was trying to use the SQL Server transport configured with MySql. This is **not** supported.

MySql can only be used in the persistence layer.

Particlular Support -

> "The SQL Server Transport unfortunately only supports SQL Server.
> Unfortunately you’ll have to select another technology to enable
> messaging."

Comment: That is correct, you mentioned an issue with persistence which *does* support MySql but as a transport only SqlServer is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing your connection string?  Could the cause be that you did not specify the correct provider name `providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"`?

```xml
<connectionStrings>
<add name="devConnectionString" connectionString="server=go.itelescope.net;port=3307;user id=xxxxxxxx;password=xxxxx;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dev"
providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I still get the same error. It's like NServiceBus still thinks it's trying to connect to a SQL Server database.